# PHP uploaded file locked by daemon

Tags: php, permissions, locking, daemon

I am actually sending a file from my android app to the localhost application server . for this i am using xampp in ubuntu, but for some unknown reason the file that are creating in the htdocs folder are owned by some user called as daemon and it is locked. Due to this my python service module (watch dog) is not able to detect the creation of the file in that folder. Plzz help as i not getting any ideas?????

```html
?php

if(isset($_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"])){
 $name = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"];
 $tmp_name = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'];
 $error = $_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'];

 if(!empty($name))
 {

  $location = './uploads/';
  
  if(!is_dir($location))
   mkdir($location);
  if(move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $location.$name))
  {
   echo "Uploaded";
  }
 }
 else
  echo 'Please choose a file';
}

?>
```

**PHP code for uploading the file**

Comment: I think it has to do something with your system instead of php. Maybe you can use the chmod function in ubuntu to change the permission of your folder

Comment: The folder permissions are already changed to my username but somehow the file created is by daemon owner which doesn't have write permissions.